# What is main difference between Apache Camel and Jboss Fuse?

Tags: frameworks

I know that Apache Camel is java open source framework and Jboss Fuse is ESB which act like container to bind camel into its container . However i need to know its differences in some more depth .

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In simplified terms, camel framework is the set of api's (java code) which are used in system integration projects whereas fuse is the server like tomcat where code is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

"JBoss Fuse combines several technologies like core Enterprise Service Bus capabilities (based on Apache Camel, Apache CXF, Apache ActiveMQ), Apache Karaf and Fabric8 in a single integrated distribution."

Deploy applications utilizing some different configurations and technologies is one of many qualities in Jboss Fuse.

"Camel" as being a rule based routing & mediation engine which can be used inside a full blown ESB, a message broker or a web services smart client. Though if you want to, you could consider that Camel is a small, lightweight embeddable ESB since it can provide many of the common ESB services like smart routing, transformation, mediation, monitoring, orchestration etc.

We should also mention what Camel isn’t. Camel isn’t an enterprise service bus **complete(ESB )**, although some call Camel a lightweight ESB because of its support for routing, transformation, monitoring, orchestration, and so forth. Camel doesn’t have a container or a reliable message bus, but it can be deployed in one, such as Open-ESB or ServiceMix. For that reason, we prefer to call
Camel an integration framework rather than an  ESB.